# Why do a dog's anal glands smell like fish?

Tags: dogs, health, fish, anatomy

What is the correlation between the two scents, chemically and otherwise?

Comment: I have heard the smell described a lot worse. Are you sure it does not just smell like this to you?

Comment: is it a common thing to sniff that part of a dogs anatomy where you live? and what does the owners of the dogs have to say about it.

Comment: @trondhansen OP is a dog by the way.

Comment: Classy, no dogs need to have their anal glands expressed every so often. (Some breeds more than others.) Let's just say I don't want to be the one to express them, I let my vet do it. Anyway when they become full, dogs become uncomfortable and start doing things like butt scooching to relieve the annoyance (and they start farting like crazy.) Trust me if you had a dog with full anal glands you would be aware of it. Sooooo, my dog's farts have been smelling like fish, any rational theories?